# Just want to know what is wrong with my SQL statement

Tags: group-by

I can't group my CourseCode Column properly using this code, can you help me how to group the CourseCode and SUM how many BSIT and ICT borrowed a book in specific month.

```
use CLS

Select C.CourseCode,
Case When DATENAME(MONTH, T.DateBorrowed) = 'January' then SUM(C.CourseCode) else 0 end as January,
Case When DATENAME(MONTH, T.DateBorrowed) = 'February' then SUM(C.CourseCode) else 0 end as February,
Case When DATENAME(MONTH, T.DateBorrowed) = 'March' then SUM(C.CourseCode) else 0 end as March
From TBL_Transactions T left outer join (TBL_Member M left outer join TBL_Course C ON M.CourseID = C.CourseID) ON T.MemberIDNo = M.MemberIDNo
Group by C.CourseCode, T.DateBorrowed!
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT C.CourseCode, DATENAME(MONTH, T.DateBorrowed), SUM(C.CourseCode)
FROM TBL_Transactions T LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(TBL_Member M LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_Course C ON M.CourseID = C.CourseID) 
ON T.MemberIDNo = M.MemberIDNo 
GROUP BY C.CourseCode, DATENAME(MONTH, T.DateBorrowed)!
```